# @RequestScopedはトランザクション制御をするか？

Tags: java, java-ee

`@RequestScoped`を付けたクラスで、1回のHTTPリクエストの処理で
(1) DBへ書き込む
(2) RuntimeExceptionをthrowする
をさせたところ、(1)の書き込み内容はDBのテーブルに書き込まれませんでした。
(2)によってロールバックされたかのような挙動ですが、`@RequestScoped`を付けただけで、そのようなトランザクション制御がされるのでしょうか？
そうだとすると、`@Transactional`は何のためにあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@RequestScoped`がトランザクション制御をするか、という質問への回答としては、「しない」となります。

DBのテーブルに書き込まれなかった、という現象についてですが、RDBMSの設定にもよります。データソースまたはJDBCでのautoCommitの設定は何になっていますでしょうか。もし、autoCommitがfalseであれば、`@Transactional`をつけていないのにロールバックされたかのような挙動になります。`@Transactional`がないのでコミットするタイミングがなく、RDBMSによってロールバックされるからです。もしこのケースであれば、RuntimeExceptionをthrowしなくても、やはりコミットするタイミングがないのでロールバックされます。

`@RequestScoped`はWebの概念でのオブジェクトのスコープ、保存期間となりますので、RDBMSのトランザクションには関わらない概念です。

Answer (score 0):

`@Transactional`で設定したトランザクションは、`RuntimeException`を throw すると、rollback されます。
（デフォルトの動作）

`@RequestScoped`は関係ないですね・・・。

Comment: `@RequestScoped`はトランザクション制御をしないはず、ということですか・・・何が原因でしょう・・・